# How can a local firm with real employees compete with upwork and sustain its owner well?

Tags: software-industry, software-development

A member of the internet writes "I enjoyed programming when I was little, so I founded a programming company at 20 and now I have two companies with multiple employees".

Then I look at Upwork and see thousands of low-wage-jobs given to desperate programmers.

Then I see a documentary on Netflix about impressive houses and the owner of the house claims to be the ex-owner of a software firm who allegedly made the money to buy and sustain the house by selling his company.

How can a local firm with real employees compete with Upwork and sustain its owner well?

Comment: So you're basically asking, how to make a successful software company whilst paying employees decent wages?

Comment: Design and offer a unique product that appeals to the market...

Comment: This seems like it would be more at home on a forum instead of a Q&A site as I don't really see a practically answerable question here. Please check the [tour] and [help/on-topic] to learn more about the sort of questions we cover here.

Comment: @Lilienthal Which forum do you recommend for this?

Comment: The short answer is "don't compete on price alone."

Comment: One strategy to get established is to do a handful of high profile jobs either at cost, or below cost, to build a strong portfolio. Focus on producing high quality work, get some strong testimonials, then charge what your work is worth. Once you have at least _some_ market presence, you should be able to find clients willing to pay for quality.

Comment: @Helena [It's a website](https://upwork.com) - a marketplace for self-employed freelancers to offer their services.

Answer (score 12):

> How can a local firm with real employees compete with upwork and sustain it's owner well?

There is no free lunch in this world. Nobody likes to work for free or provide top skills for something less. You get what you pay for. If you see carefully most of the desperate programmers are usually in the learning phase and doing side projects. If someone is really skilled they won't lower their per hour charge as they can find better rate somewhere else.

Besides this is an economic concept of supply & demand. And any business whether a software company or not is prone to outsourcing. So as an owner/director of that company it's your decision whether to make or buy.

Comment: Yep, I've worked at companies who have tried to go the cheap route (always against my advice). It's always ended up coming back to bite them. Either the quality is bad and they end up fixing it in-house at higher cost than it would have been to build it in-house, or they pass it off to the client as it is and risk losing a client.

Comment: How do you build a good-reputation software company and get enough well paid work?

Comment: @BrutusCruciatus I think you might be interested in the blog of one of the founders of this particular website, Joel on Software: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/ It has over 1000 articles written basically about the experience of one person trying to do just that.

Answer (score 8):

> How can a local firm with real employees compete with upwork and
>   sustain it's owner well?

You compete the same way any other business competes - by offering something others don't.

If your client base values only price, you won't be able to compete with any race-to-the-bottom company like upwork.

So you find a client base that has values other than just price. Many clients will value quality, availability, a history of success, continuity, onsite presence, specific expertise, etc. A local company with good people could easily offer all of those benefits. Many do.

Answer (score 4):

When you hire someone on upwork, you are hiring just one person. If you have a one person job, that's all you need (just hope that the person is actually reliable and knows what they are doing).

But most projects require multiple people with different skillsets to get the job done. If you hire all these people from the web, you have a bunch of online contacts with people who have never met each other. Now good luck getting all these people to work as a team and create the product you need. They won't be able to coordinate on their own. You will have to micro-manage them. That's going to be a full-time job.

When you hire a software development company, on the other hand, you are hiring a whole team of people who already know each other and are used to working with each other. You also hire the people who manage them, plan the project and give you the advise you need in order to make strategic decisions about the project. There is a lot more you get than just developer-hours.

Also, if the software company fails to deliver, you might be able to sue them and actually get some compensation for damages out of them. If you smash a private person with a six-figures lawsuit, you will just force them to declare personal bankruptcy and you won't see any money.